# Submitting data through forms into a collection

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm creating a feedback **modal** that allows the users to submit me a feedback about the webpage. The code for the **form** inside the modal is:

```
 <div class="modal-body">

 <form class='feedbackForm'>
 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="form-control">Feedback</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="feedbackForm" 
 id="feedbackForm" placeholder="Feedback">
 </div>

 <div class="modal-footer">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-
 dismiss="modal">Close</button>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Feedback</button>
 </div>

 </form>
 </div>
```

and the helper for the same is :

```
"submit .feedbackForm": function(event){
var Feedbackvar = event.target.Feedbackvar.value;

//Insert feedback
Feedback.insert({
  FeedbackData: 'Feedbackvar'
});
}
```

Also, I'm using the collections 2 package and have defined a schema for the feedback collection:

```
Feedback = new Mongo.Collection("feedback");
Feedback.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
FeedbackData:{
type: String
},

userId:{
type: String,
autoValue: function(){
  return Meteor.userId()
}
},

CreatedAt:{
  type: Date,
  autoValue: function(){
    return new Date()
  }
}
}));
```

The problem is I am not able to insert the feedback to the collection with the help of the form, but with the help of the console, I can insert the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot wrong here, but the following should provide a quick fix:

- Change `event.target.Feedbackvar.value` to `event.target.feedbackForm.value`
- Take `Feedbackvar` out of quotes in your `insert` - this is just trying to insert the `string` "FeedbackVar"

Those changes should make it work, but you'll still want to spend time reviewing this whole thing - for example, your `form` has `class` `feedbackForm`, which is the same as the `name` of your  `input` as well as its `id` - very confusing.

You might also want to consider a `textarea` rather than a simple `text input` for a feedback form.

Comment: To get the input from the form, the `form class` and the `input id` should be the same. I tried fiddling and this configuration worked for me. Plus the changes you suggested worked. Thank You.